# how to install grunt-sass to work with libsass

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, libsass

I'm trying to install grunt-sass but I'm having problems in the process.
I'm following the grunt-sass [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) and the node-gyp [documentation](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/), but still not working.
I attach a screenshot with the errors. Somebody knows what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have VS 2013 as [stated in the docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#install) and [experienced in this issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/415).

> Compiling versions 0.9.4 and above on Windows machines requires Visual Studio 2013 WD. If you have multiple VS versions, use npm install with the --msvs_version=2013 flag.

Or it could have to do with [this reported issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/467) and the binaries need to be rebuilt.